# $(this) does not work inside onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

```
<head>
    <script>
        function call() {
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            alert(id);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-id="5" onclick="call();"></div>
</body>
```

This is my javascript function between `<script>` tags. When it called `id` shown as `undefined`. Why `$(this)` is not working?

Comment: Why not just pass the ID inside the `call()` function instead? No need to over complicate your code surely?

Comment: `this` refers to `window` context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass the element as the parameter of `call()` function like following.

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function call(elm) {
            var id = $(elm).data("id");
            alert(id);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-id="5" onclick="call(this);">Click Here</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It should work. I guess you missed jQuery reference. @jjkk